# "Error: ENOTFOUND" when making a lot of requests from Node.js request package

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest

I am running a script in Node.js that uses the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) package to help me make HTTP requests. The script makes anywhere from 100 to 1000 requests in order to download PDFs and put them in a certain folder on my local machine. When I only make 100 requests, the program works fine and all the PDFs show up in my folder, but when I make many more requests the program begins throwing this error (ENOTFOUND) and the files that throw this error are blank in the folder. When I load the links that threw the error manually, they work fine (so I know it is not an issue with the host) and I can download the files like that, but I would like to automate it.

Here is the bit of the function that gives the error. I have begun trying to push all links that give errors to an array, but have had no luck fixing the issue yet.

```
  var year = process.argv[3] % 2000;
  var url  = yearURL[year];

  request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
              var $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true});

              $('link', 'item').each(function(){
                    var link = $(this).text();
                    PDFscrape(link);
              });
        }
  });

  function PDFscrape(link){
        request(link, function(error, response, html){
              if(!error){
                    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                    var num = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblFile2', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageDetails').text();
                    console.log('Document ' + num + ' has been loaded.');
                    var i = 1;
                    $('a', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblAttachments2').each(function(){
                          var pdf = 'https://phila.legistar.com/' + $(this).attr('href');
                          AddPDF(pdf, num, i);
                          i++;
                    });
              }
        })
  }

  function AddPDF(link, file, i){
        var name = file;
        var fileName;
        if (year !== 100 && year !== -2){
              fileName = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/pdfs/20' + year + '/' + file + '_' + i + '.pdf');
        } else if (year === 100){
              fileName = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/pdfs/recent100/' + file + '_' + i + '.pdf');            
        } else if (year === -2){
              fileName = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/pdfs/recent10/' + file + '_' + i + '.pdf');                        
        }

        request({
              uri: link,
              headers: {
                    'Host': 'phila.legistar.com',
                    'User-Agent': 'request'
              }
        }, function(err) {
              if (err){
                    var errLink = {url: link, file: name, num: i}
                    var count = errors.push(errLink);
                    console.log('--------- Error: ' + count + ' ---------');
              }
        }).pipe(fileName);
  }
```

The error that is being thrown is:

```
  stream.js:94
        throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
        at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
        at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Note: I am handling the error, but the documents that give this error are piped through as blank when they should not be. I just can't figure out why the files are giving the error.

Comment: You should post more code, and possibly show the actual error/trace thrown (so we know what the offending line is). A wild guess: the whole thing is in a loop, and `file` refers to the last loop iteration? (Just a guess)

Comment: Sure. I'll describe the overall flow first: I'm starting with an RSS feed that has anywhere from 10 to >1000 links in it. I am scraping the feed for each link, going to that URL and then piping the 1 or 2 PDFs on each page. The links to the PDFs (on the page I have scraped from the RSS feed), start an automatic download, they are not a link to load the PDF in the browser. So I am piping the download to a folder on my local machine.

Comment: I edited the above post to show the completed AddPDF function that gets called for every PDF link. Let me know if I should post more code.

Answer (score 0):

A few missing semicolons, somewhat inelegant use of `!=` instead of `!==`, bad double-meaning use of `file`, but nothing to explain what you're seeing. I am guessing that `year` is somehow bad. Posting my version of your code here with some comments.

(I am posting here and not in a comment b/c can't post long code in comments):

```
function AddPDF(link, filename, i) {
    var file;
    if (year !== 100 && year !== -2) {
        // probably want "!==" rather than "=="
        file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + file + '_' + i + '.pdf');
    } else {
        // WHAT HAPPENS HERE?
        // what is "file", that is later piped to?
        // this may be your issue.
        // Where is this "year" coming from? Can you show relevant code?
    }

    request({
        uri: link,
        headers: {
            'Host': 'phila.legistar.com',
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    }, function(err) {
        var errLink, count;
        if (err) {
            errLink = {url: link, file: filename, num: i};
            count = errors.push(errLink);
            console.log('--------- Error: ' + count + ' ---------');
        }
    }).pipe(file);
}
```

Finally, you still haven't provided the actual trace.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've updated the code above. With what I think is the relevant code. Yeah is being chosen by one of the inputs to the program, and an array is indexed to get the URL to the RSS feed for that year.

Comment: Just realized I have a few more of those "double-meanings" with the url variable, but that shouldn't be where the issue is coming from. Although I am changing it to be sure.

Comment: Can you also post the actual error message (trace) you're seeing?

Comment: (A side note: declare `var filename` only once at the top of your function, and assign it to in the various "then" clauses without repeating the `var` keyword; also, what is `yearName`, a typo?)

Comment: After further looking, what is `num`? Is it guaranteed to be something that you can create a file name from? Before downloading each PDF, print `num` to the console, just to make sure it would form a legal filename.

Comment: Just posted the trace. Yes yearName was a typo, meant to type fileName (I am testing the first `if` statement because that is the one that gives the error so I didn't catch it). `num` is what I expect it to be. It is the PDF's file number given by the site I am scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Good thing you posted the error... It seems like what you have is a DNS error. Hostname lookup is failing sometimes.

I suggest you print all of the URL's, without actually downloading them. If they all look OK, then it's a temporary DNS issue. If you have a local/close DNS server, check its logs. Otherwise, try changing the DNS to something robust, like 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS), just for the test.

If that fails as well, for different URLs every time, then it's something in your local machine. One way around it is to try/catch this and re-try the offending URL.

Comment: Because most links are working fine (usually about 1/4 fails, although it can vary), I'm assuming it has to do with the server I am scraping, not my local machine. 

Can you explain changing to a robust DNS again? If I know the issue is not with the URLs being bad, but rather the server I am attempting to connect to, is this still something I should try?

Lastly, I had attempted pushing all bad URLs to an array, and then iterating through the array to re-try all of the URLs but was getting confused with the asynchronous JavaScript. Would a try/catch work better?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It could be a temporary DNS issue on your end, or it could be that the server returns a redirect to a host that does not exist. Start with changing your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 first and let's see how that goes. (Also, you could try to tell `request` to not follow redirects. It some PDF's go missing but the error doesn't occur then it's bad redirects from the server).

Comment: I actually already had my DNS server listed as 8.8.8.8 so it wasn't that, and telling `request` to not follow redirects didn't help either.